# $host_name variable in SSL certificate path in Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl

I'm trying to set up a default server in nginx with SSL, path to SSL certificate should contain sitename, something like that

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name _;
    ssl_certificate ssl/$http_host/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/$http_host/privkey.pem;
```

and it doesn't work - in error log
`cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl//fullchain.pem"`
If I print this variable in headers with add_header XX "$http_host"; it shows the proper sitename. Is there any way to use sitename in certificate path? There are a lot of sites on my server with typical config so it's better for me to have just one config. Nginx version 1.18 and if I manually define some variable and put it in `ssl_certificate` parameter everything is working fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nginx use $server\_name on ssl\_certificate path](https://serverfault.com/questions/505015/nginx-use-server-name-on-ssl-certificate-path)

Comment: This doesn't look like a duplicate of that question at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is no variable `$host_name` in nginx. Most likely you want to use `$host`.

Comment: Thank you - it was a typo. I use $http_host with the same result

Comment: $http_host is extracted from the request headers processed but in your case it is used when nginx is starting and there are no requests yet to process. Use $host as suggested but you'll need to change your server_name.