# nginx dynamic ssl_certificate/_key

Tags: nginx

Not sure what's happening, but this one works:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/tld/$ssl_server_name/ssl.crt;
```

and this one fails:

```
set $cert $ssl_server_name;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/tld/$cert/ssl.crt;
```

The real case is: my certs are located in folder by TLD (don't ask):

```
map $ssl_server_name $tld {
   ~^(.+\.)*(.+)$      $2;
   default $ssl_server_name;
}
```

But it seems like I can only use `$ssl_server_name`. Anything else fails.

```
*1 cannot load certificate "/etc/ssl/tld//ssl.crt": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/ssl/tld//ssl.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file) while SSL handshaking, client: 192.168.136.xxx, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

```
nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: Have you tried using a named capture? For example: `~^(.+\.)*(?<myname>.+)$ $myname;`

Comment: Just tried. It fails. Note that even "set $cert $ssl_server_name;" fails

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone stumbles upon this as the first search result:
Working solution can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1103797/1061598).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).